# How to manipulate mhlo attributes

Tags: c++11, llvm-ir

Can someone share how to manipulate the attributes of mhlo ops? For `mhlo::DotGeneralOp` as an example, it has `mhlo::DotDimensionNumbersAttr` which consists of

```
lhsBatchingDimensions
rhsBatchingDimensions
lhsContractingDimensions
rhsContractingDimensions
```

Each of these are of type `::llvm::ArrayRef<int64_t>`. When I want to change the values of `lhsBatchingDimensions` for example, what would be the best way?